# The email field is required but no input email in view Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

I keep getting this error message:

> - The email field is required.

But I don't have any input type with a name of email in my view:

Login

```
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ asset('img/logo.png') }}" type="image/x-icon">

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,800" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/bootstrap.min.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/feather.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('css/style.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.css') }}">

</head>

<body>

    <section class="login-block">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <form action="/login" method="post" class="md-float-material form-material">
                        @csrf
                        <div class="auth-box card">
                            <div class="card-block">
                                <div class="row m-b-20">
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <h3 class="text-center">Members Management System</h3>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                @if ($errors)
                                <div class="alert alert-danger background-danger">
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                                        <i class="icofont icofont-close-line-circled text-white"></i>
                                    </button>
                                    @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                                        - {{ $error }}
                                        <br>
                                    @endforeach
                                </div>
                                @endif

                                <div class="form-group form-primary">
                                    <input type="text" name="employee_id" class="form-control" required=""
                                        placeholder="Employee ID">
                                    <span class="form-bar"></span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group form-primary">
                                    <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" required=""
                                        placeholder="Password">
                                    <span class="form-bar"></span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row m-t-30">
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <button type="submit"
                                            class="btn btn-primary btn-md btn-block waves-effect waves-light text-center m-b-20">
                                            SIGN IN
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <script src="{{ asset('js/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('js/jquery-ui.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('js/script.js') }}"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

I don't understand why the `$errors` is notifying me of error regarding email. Any suggestions? I didn't modify any default AUTH settings from Laravel. It may seem that the error is coming from other source?

EDIT:

Thanks for suggesting to override the `username()` in my `LoginController` by:

```
public function username()
{
    return 'employee_id';
}
```

Is this the most conventional and preferred way to do this? Thank you for the assist.

Comment: By default laravel setup email and password as basic auth so you need to override it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AuthenticatesUsers` is responsible for validating the data after the user submitted the form. If you take a look at this file, you will see this method:

```
/**
 * Validate the user login request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return void
 */
protected function validateLogin(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        $this->username() => 'required|string',
        'password' => 'required|string',
    ]);
}
```

More specifically, as you can see, this method is in charge for calling the validator on the fields name "password" and by the method username(). If you only wanted to custom the username field, you could overwrite the username() method in LoginController class:

```
public function username()
{
    return 'employee_id';
}
```

But since you want to custom both the username field name and the password field name, I suggest that you overwrite the validateLogin() method in the LoginController class:

```
protected function validateLogin(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'employee_id' => 'required|string',
        'user_password' => 'required|string',
    ]);
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: So this means that I just need to do the overwriting in the LoginController and not the AuthenticateUsers file itself?

Comment: yes, you just need to overwrite on `LoginController`

Comment: it worked when I did a `public function username() { return "employee_id"; }` in my LoginController

Comment: Yes, that's what i suggested in my answer :) and I'm glad you've got the solution

Answer (score 1):

You can refer `employee_id`, as `username`, on login.
Now, open LoginController, and add the `username()` method.

`public function username() { 
   return "username"; 
}`

Now, you can login without e-mail address.

Comment: wait is it `return "username"` or `return "emplyee_id"`?

Comment: You should give your users/employees, usernames, and use `username`, not employee_id :)